# Install4j What is the counterpart under MacOS for create a Windows URL Link

Tags: hyperlink, install4j, dock

I want to ship my application with an installer created by Install4J. The installation itself works, but I want to place a link in the dock or on the Desktop on macOS. Is there a counterpart for the action "create a Windows URL Link", that can be used for Apple OS?